# Create RDF with nested nodes in Apache Jena

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web, jena

A similiar question was asked already here [How to get nested RDF/XML from Jena?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476022/how-to-get-a-nested-structure-in-jena).

I didn't find the answer helpful: As the author I want to map something like this:

```
<address>
   <street>...</street>
   <postcode>...</postcode>
   .
   .
   .
</adress>
```

The answer was given that in RDF you have to think about triples, but doesn't apply that here?

- (Address, has street, ...)
- (Address, has postcode, ...)
- (Person, has address, ...)

Another reason why I am asking, I have used Jena Bean to generate RDF out of my Java Class Model and the result was also a nested structure. Now I want to do the same with Apache Jena and I can't get it figured out, no hint in the document, I tried it out, no idea so far.

Comment: Have you tried the official tutorial? It's shown how to do what you're asking about. They're using a predefined dictionary for the VCard namespace, which comes with Jena jars but it's easy to define your own dictionary just after a glance at the predefined ones. Here's the tutorial http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Introduction

Comment: That's it, thanks! If you create an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I updated my answer to point you to a really great tool that you'll need while writing RDF. Be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the official tutorial? It's shown how to do what you're asking about.

They're using a predefined dictionary for the VCard namespace, which comes with Jena jars but it's easy to define your own dictionary just after a glance at the predefined ones.

Here's the tutorial http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Introduction

You should also check out the RDF Validator: http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/
It allows you to validate your RDF (who would've guessed) and also to visualize it as a graph. It really helps you see and realize the mistakes you make while creating an ontology. It saved me lots of fruitless efforts and frustration.